# jScrollPane not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

im trying to load jscrollpane when ajax loads, the function seems to load but its not working very well, it's behaving like theres no content in the jscrollpane div but it have! i dont know what im doing wrong

```
$('#feedbackNoticia #noticia2').click(function(){
                $.post('teste2.php', function(data){
                    $('#noticiasBox .descricao').fadeOut(200);
                    $('#noticiasBox .noticiaAberta').delay(200).fadeIn(200).html(data);
                    $('.ajax .pNoticias').jScrollPane();
                });
            });
```

when the ajax file loads 'teste2.php' it shows the jscrollpane's html extructure as you can see in the inspector but it doesnt work and i have no idea why.

you can see the example here, click in the menu Notícias and then you'll scroll down and click in the last item
http://www.estudiocaju.com.br/homolog/dicavalcanti/

Comment: Did you fix it? It seems to be working...

Comment: yes i fixed it, i forgot to post the answer. ill do it now

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i had a `.delay(100)` after the fadeIn, somehow it was affecting the jScrollPane loading.